# Accept User Input at run time from Outlook 365 for a Python Script

Tags: python-3.x, vba, outlook

I am working on a python Script which needs to run within Outlook 365. I have done this using VBA i.e by passing the python script location in the VBA module and created an Outlook ribbon for the same.

Now my python script requires **inputs from user at run time which needs to come from Outlook and not from Python Shell**. Like if my python script is running in the background and waiting for user input, rather taking values from the Python shell it should accept whatever I am typing in the Outlook as input.

I checked for this online but couldn't find anything concrete regarding this.

VBA Module to run python Script

Sub get_mail()

```
Shell "python C:\some_path\final_script.py"
```

End Sub